# Exported model does not contain the animation

Tags: animation, shape-keys, gltf

I built a folding plane (to paper plane), and animated it without bones, using AnimAll.
The animation plays okay on blender, but it does not appear when exported .gltf or any other type.

Here is my hirearchy:
[image: scene hirearchy]

And here are my shape keys:
[image: shape keys]

And here is my .blend file:

[image]

Comment: You won't be able to export AnimAll animations to formats like glTF. Alembic will work though.

Comment: Thank you, your reply helped me solving this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the solution, helped by this response to another thread:
[GLTFLoader: Very large bounding box w/ morph targets #18809](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/18809#issuecomment-594629778)

AnimAll animation is not supported to formats like glTF, and what you have to do is:

1. export the object as a .mmd
2. set the timeline to 0
3. delete the object animation
4. import the .mmd file to it

This will add keyframes for the animation.
A problem that appeared is that after adding the .mmd the animation was playing super slow and shaky.
And the reply I got at my question helped me fix this; Before exporting to mmd, you should delete the materials and the modifications.
After adding the .mmd file back, you can re-add them and now everything is ready to be exported to glTF

Comment: For future readers: It's MDD(NewTek MDD Format) not mmd!